# Fancybox video gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I'm trying to make a video gallery with fancybox using some of the tutorials I found for image galleries, but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. All I have is an icon that displays a fancybox with all my iframes I and want to transform the video container into a video gallery.

This is my HTML:

```
<a id="videoIcon" href="#video" class="fancybox">
    <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/512/photo-video-start-icon.png" width="33" height="33">
</a>

<div id="video" style="display: none;" data-fancybox-group="gallery">
    <iframe class="fancybox_iframe" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2plsuh" width="480" height="269" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <iframe class="fancybox_iframe" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2pn6zo" width="480" height="269" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <iframe class="fancybox_iframe" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2pn66h" width="480" height="269" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <iframe class="fancybox_iframe" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2pjpvg" width="480" height="269" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <iframe class="fancybox_iframe" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2pn6wd" width="480" height="269" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <iframe class="fancybox_iframe" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2pn61r" width="480" height="269" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <iframe class="fancybox_iframe" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2p5add" width="480" height="269" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <iframe class="fancybox_iframe" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2or2yc" width="480" height="269" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <iframe class="fancybox_iframe" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2of336" width="480" height="269" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

And this is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#videoIcon").fancybox();
    $(".fancybox_iframe").fancybox({
        type : 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/juanorero/qgt7t231/)

Thank you and sorry for my bad English

P.S: The iframes are obtained using an ajax call and placing the response in a template with Handlebars.js, so the div that contains all the videos is actually empty at the beginning. Nevertheless, I don't think this is relevant for the solution.